# C++ delete does not find destructor

Tags: casting, c++-cli, destructor

I want to know why ~Test2 and ~Test1 are not called in this case:

```
public class Test1
{
public:
    Test1() { Console::WriteLine("Test1\n"); }
    virtual ~Test1() { Console::WriteLine("~Test1\n"); }
};

class Test2 : public Test1
{
public:
    Test2()  { Console::WriteLine("Test2\n"); }
    virtual ~Test2() { Console::WriteLine("~Test2\n"); }
};

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Console::WriteLine(L"Testing destructors");

    //Test1* t1 = new Test2(); // Test2 is cast as Test1
    //delete t1;

    //Console::ReadKey();
    //Console::WriteLine(L"Now void*:");

    void*  v = new Test2(); 
    delete v;

    Console::ReadKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Is this a 
- A rule that requires all compilers act this way? 
- A bug in C++ compiler implementation? 
- A behavior left undefined and so it varies from compiler to compiler?

Comment: the (incomplete) type void  has neither constructor nor destructor.

Comment: `a bug in C++ compiler implementation?` No. `An undefined compiler requirement?` No. `Or a rule that requires all compilers act this way?` Yes. Assuming C++-cli isn't different from C++ in this regard.

Comment: @user2079303: Can you point me to a spec that says so?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a virtual destructor in the base class. This will get you the expected behavior. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

```
virtual ~Test1() { Console::WriteLine("~Test1\n"); }
```

More Details here:

- [Virtual Destructor](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/virtual-destructor/)
- [Destructor and Finalizer in C++/CLI](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/602834a8-188b-435c-9826-7072c4875204/destructor-and-finalizer-in-ccli?forum=vclanguage)

Comment: Yes you are right. Virtual is what is missing. That was a silly question in retrospect. Now uncomment those 2 other lines:     
    //void*  v = new Test1();
    //delete v;

No destructor is now called as a result of delete v; Why is that?           P.S. Sorry but I edited the question and now the answer no longer fits. You did answer the previous version.

Answer (score 0):

It does not call the destructor because the pointer you are calling delete on is not a pointer to your object type. How is delete supposed to know that a `void*` is pointing to a particular type? It can't. So it simply deletes the memory since `void` has no destructor.

Comment: How does delete know? Well how does it know the type when I downcast it from Test2 to Test1 as in the commented out code and then delete it?

Answer (score 0):

`t1` is a void, it is not of type `Test1`, the compiler has no way of knowing that you want to delete a `Test1`. You can try casting it back:

```
delete static_cast<Test1*>(t1);
```

Comment: Compiler may not know but between compiler and run-time it is knowable if that's a word. For example in this code:  Test1* t1 = new Test2();  delete t1; it still knows to call ~Test2. Also a workaround is not what I am looking for.